Convert MD5 to BigInt on Amazon Redshift
I have the following C# code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string profileId = "TEST";
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            string playerGroup;
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(profileId);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            long hashCode = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashBytes, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(hashCode);
        }
    }
}

The result: -1956981089572930813
I want to replicate the same process in SQL (Amazone Redshift).
But I get a different result.
If I do:
select from_hex(substring(md5('TEST'), 1, 16))::bigint

The result: 233018722177570788
Is there any way to reproduce the C# process on SQL (Redshift)?
I tried:
select from_hex(substring(md5('TEST'), 1, 16))::bigint

I was expecting: -1956981089572930813
I get: 233018722177570788

There are a number of possible issues going on here.
You are dealing with two different representations of the 128 bit md5 hash - C# is in a 16 byte binary array while Redshift is a 32 character string of hexadecimal digits.  As the C# docs state:
"The ComputeHash methods of the MD5 class return the hash as an array of 16 bytes. Note that some MD5 implementations produce a 32-character, hexadecimal-formatted hash. To interoperate with such implementations, format the return value of the ComputeHash methods as a hexadecimal value."
My first recommendation would be to compare the result of the MD5 functions as hex strings.  This will give you an idea if things are equal at this first step. These could be different for a few reasons, the biggest of which would be endianness (the order in how bit level data is handled by the hardware).
Since hex is 16 values (4 bits) per byte of storage and byte array data has 256 values (8 bits) per byte of storage then data density is half.  (It looks like this isn't news to you by your code.)  In converting from byte data to hex you may see character pair flipped - does bits 0-3 come before or after bits 4-7?  This is the endianness problem.  You will need to again look at these functions in isolation to see how they behave and if data manipulations are needed to produce an equivalent result.
Your code looks good at a quick review so I'm leaning toward endian issues as a cause.  Going through a step by step debug process will help fix such issues but also show if other concerns are in play. Endianness can be pain to deal with but there are code snippets you can find to help resolve these.  There are even endian tests that your C# code can run to determine what MD5 process to run.  Have you see differences in C# MD5 result when run on different computer architectures?
